# Missing dll files when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, qt, dll, pyinstaller

Good day!

I'm using python 3.5.2 with qt5, pyqt5 and sip14.8.
I'm also using the latest pyinstaller bracnch (3.3.dev0+g501ad40).

I'm trying to create an exe file for a basic hello world program.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

class newPingDialog(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super(newPingDialog, self).__init__()
    self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
    self.setWindowTitle("hello!")
    self.show()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
GUI = newPingDialog()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

At first, I used to get some errors regarding crt-msi. So I've reinstalled SDK and c++ runtime and added them to my environment.
But now I keep getting errors about missing dlls (qsvg, Qt5PrintSupport)

```
6296 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Svg.dll dependency of C:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-pac
kages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qsvg.dll
6584 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Svg.dll dependency of C:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-pac
kages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\iconengines\qsvgicon.dll
6992 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5PrintSupport.dll dependency of C:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\printsupport\windowsprintersupport.dll
7535 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5PrintSupport.dll dependency of c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
\site-packages\PyQt5\QtPrintSupport.pyd
8245 INFO: Looking for eggs
8245 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python35.dll
8246 INFO: Found binding redirects:
```

I've checked and both dlls exist and have their PATH set. I also tried to manually add them to my dist folder, but it didn't helped.

I'll highly appreciate any advice you might have!

Comment: 'insert a `dll` in your exe' is hard way. try add `as source` to builder configuration. A thing  `from x import y` not eual to `import x.y` or `import x.y as z`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This may be more like a workaround and Pyinstaller might need fixing.

I found out that `--paths` argument pointing to the directory containing *Qt5Core.dll*, *Qt5Gui.dll*, etc. helped

```
pyinstaller --paths C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin hello.py
```

Comment: It worked! I've spent 3 days on it, and your solution worked! thank you!

Comment: The same for me. Thanks very much for this tipp. I was close to giving up on it. With --paths it works.

Comment: If you use a virtual environment you can also set the --paths to `venv\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin`.

Comment: Inside the spec file, there is also the `HOMEPATH` variable that can [automatically expand](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#globals-available-to-the-spec-file) to python installation directory. Here, it's `C:\Python35\Lib\site-package\ `. It's more portable than hardcoded paths., and here it equals to `HOMEPATH + \\PyQt5\Qt\bin`

Answer (score 3):

I read all complicated solutions on github and stackoverflow for this problem.
However, the below simple solution is what worked for me:

Step 1: pip3 uninstall pyinstaller

Step 2: pip install pyinstaller

Step 3: pyinstaller --onefile filename.py

I tried this solution on 2 different computers which were facing the same problem.
Both worked.
Please let me know if this works for you as well. Thumbs up would be appreciated after that.
Cheers

Comment: doesn't work for most modules using dll's i had to manually --add-data the dll's themselves from out of the virtualenv

Comment: Worked for me; I suspect because I had some sort of Python version mismatch (it was complaining about lack of python38.dll when I was using Python 3.9).

Answer (score 2):

This has now been fixed in the latest development branch of PyInstaller, see [this Issue for PyInstaller on GitHub](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2152).

Answer (score 0):

Normally adding `--Path` argument pointing directory containing unfound library solves the problem. There might be a problem if command string parsing if you are using PyInstaller 3.3dev. This generally happens if the path contains spaces. In such case, you can modify `pathex` argument in `.spec` file generated by PyInstaller and then run it with PyInstaller to build executable.

```
pyinstaller file_name.spec
```

Hopefully, this will be fixed soon.....

Answer (score 0):

> 26095 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\DLLs\select.pyd

Search in C: drive for dll and set the path in pyinstaller command. The below command fixed the above pyinstaller error in windows 10:

```
pyinstaller --paths "C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-m..namespace-downlevel_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_none_50c6cb8431e7428f" hello.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows 10 and had to delete the data in the C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\pyinstaller directory and reinstall pyinstaller for it to work.

Answer (score -3):

can use "pyinstaller --onefile filename.py".  exe file will be created in dist folder