# PyQt5 ImportError after running standalone executable created by PyInstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, pyqt5

I have a fully working PyQt5 project, now trying to make a standalone executable that is preferably OS independent.

I am using *PyInstaller-3.2* in ubuntu 14.04 for this purpose. Tried the following command.

```
pyinstaller --additional-hooks-dir=. -F <file-path>
```

Everything works, but when I have run the particular executable, received the following ImportError:

> ImportError: No module named PyQt5

Later, I have found out that I need to include some PyInstaller hooks to import PyQt5

As my related imports throughout the project were:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
```

So, I have added some hooks namely `hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py`, `hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py`, `hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py`, `hook-PyQt5.uic.py` which content is more or less like below:

```
hiddenimports = ["PyQt5.QtCore.*"]
```

Then I run the PyInstaller command.

```
pyinstaller --additional-hooks-dir=. -F <file-path>
```

But, unfortunately, I got the same importError.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You might need to set the `--path` argument or your pyinstaller command. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674400/missing-dll-files-when-using-pyinstaller

Comment: @MrLeeh, doesn't work.