# PyInstaller: Lib not Found 'mpich2mpi.dll'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am compiling a project with PyInstaller into a Windows Executable on Windows 7 64-bit OS. I run pyinstaller with the following command:

```
pyinstaller SHARPpy-win7-64.spec --onefile --noconsole --hiddenimport=tkinter --clean --upx-dir='C:\Users\[User]\Downloads\upx-3.95-win64
```

And receive the following errors (output is reduced to warnings/errors only):

```
39710 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of C:\Users\WDSS\Anaconda2\env
s\SHARPpy_20190117\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.dll
46004 WARNING: lib not found: pgc14.dll dependency of C:\Users\WDSS\Anaconda2\en
vs\SHARPpy_20190117\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
46068 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90rtl.dll dependency of C:\Users\WDSS\Anaconda2
\envs\SHARPpy_20190117\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
46142 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90.dll dependency of C:\Users\WDSS\Anaconda2\en
vs\SHARPpy_20190117\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
47220 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of C:\Users\WDSS\Anaconda
2\envs\SHARPpy_20190117\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_lp64.dll
48815 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of C:\Users\WDSS\Anaconda2\en
vs\SHARPpy_20190117\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_lp64.dll
49401 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of C:\Users\WDSS\Anaconda
2\envs\SHARPpy_20190117\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_ilp64.dll
54938 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of C:\Users\WDSS\Anaconda2\env
s\SHARPpy_20190117\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.dll
70266 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of C:\Users\WDSS\Anaconda2\en
vs\SHARPpy_20190117\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_ilp64.dll
```

The python program relies on the following packages and is loosely related to the SHARPpy code:

```
numpy,pyrebase,PySide1.2.1
```

Is anyone familiar with this error or know how to troubleshoot it? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It could be a similar problem to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38682416/7554387. You may have to add a path to your used package/packages.

Comment: Apparently these dll's are not on the computer I am trying to compile on, but the program works perfect when run manually.

Comment: Was there a final resolution here Jordan?  I have the same issue