# Python code works on interpreter but not when I use pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am creating a bot and I am using libs like pandas, numpy and sklearn and I have also installed all these libraries in a virtual env. The bot works fine on Pycharm but when I use pyinstaller and create a standalone, it's standalone shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 167, in __init__
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\vabha\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI38962\sklearn\.libs\vcomp140.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chandlerbing.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

Console debbug say **FileNotFoundError**... Let me translate it for you.
`vcomp140.dll is missing and need to be used` you had it on temporary location and now is not any more. Try also look [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38682416/10234009) or you can try also [Auto Py To Exe](https://dev.to/eshleron/how-to-convert-py-to-exe-step-by-step-guide-3cfi) maybe will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have all the libraries installed in the same environment as pyinstaller. You probably installed pyinstaller in a global environment so you should install the libraries in the globa environment.