# Missing .dll files for open source geospatial repo's when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, dll, pyinstaller

I am trying to package a geospatial tool up for my team that turns points to lines and writes them to a postgres database. Everything is working well in the GUI when running from a python interpreter. When I try to use pyinstaller to package the code into an .exe I am getting multiple errors of missing .dll file. I have tried multiple other solutions from questions posted here: [Missing dll files when using pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674400/missing-dll-files-when-using-pyinstaller) and other stack overflow resources. Here is my command prompt when trying to create the .exe sorry for the length.

```
(arcpro_testing) C:\Users\JacobNordberg\Documents\GitHub\Point-to-Line2>pyinstaller --

onefile ptlgui.py
```

When I run the initial pyinstaller command it runs until it tells me to add in  `import sys ; sys.setrecursionlimit(sys.getrecursionlimit() * 5)` to the .spec file. I had to remove some of the information in the command prompt for length limits, please let me know if more information would be helpful.

```
(arcpro_testing) C:\Users\JacobNordberg\Documents\GitHub\Point-to-Line2>pyinstaller ptlgui.spec
881 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.4.0, contrib hooks: 2024.1
882 INFO: Python: 3.9.11 (conda)
887 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
889 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\Documents\\GitHub\\Point-to-Line2']
1209 INFO: checking Analysis
1209 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
1209 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
1210 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
1222 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3351 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 
91290 WARNING: Hidden import "mx.DateTime" not found!
91396 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook tensorflow from 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-tensorflow.py'.
91594 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sklearn.tree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
91656 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
91658 INFO: Matplotlib backend selection method: automatic discovery of used backends
92088 INFO: Trying determine the default backend as first importable candidate from the list: ['Qt5Agg', 'Gtk3Agg', 'TkAgg', 'WxAgg']
92553 INFO: Selected matplotlib backends: ['Qt5Agg']
93189 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
95526 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
95706 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
96106 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
96288 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
96289 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py' from 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
96291 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.stats._stats.py' from 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
96887 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools._distutils.command.check.py' from 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
97884 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlalchemy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
98163 WARNING: Hidden import "pysqlite2" not found!
98164 WARNING: Hidden import "MySQLdb" not found!
98588 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
98589 INFO: checking Tree
98590 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
98590 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
98659 INFO: checking Tree
98659 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
98660 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
98670 INFO: checking Tree
98671 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
98671 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
98675 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-tzdata.py' from 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
99893 INFO: Performing binary vs. data reclassification (5701 entries)
100713 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
100717 WARNING: Ignoring AppKit.framework/AppKit imported from C:\Users\JacobNordberg\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcpro_testing\lib\site-packages\darkdetect\_mac_detect.py - only basenames are supported with ctypes imports!
100884 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
100918 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
100920 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
100923 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook _pyi_rth_utils from 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-_pyi_rth_utils.py'.
100924 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_pyi_rth_utils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
100926 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
100928 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
100932 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
100933 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_setuptools.py'
100935 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_traitlets.py'
100936 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pywintypes.py'
100936 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
100942 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pyproj.py'
100943 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_osgeo.py'
100946 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
101287 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
C:\Users\JacobNordberg\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcpro_testing\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py:194: UserWarning: The numpy.array_api submodule is still experimental. See NEP 47.
  __import__(package)
106143 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (AddDllDirectory): ['C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\bin', 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\pyzmq.libs', 'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\bin']
106143 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (PATH): ['C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin']
111753 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'gdal-7f64690bf4c72c16286ddb94018eb5f1.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\_transform.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111754 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'gdal-7f64690bf4c72c16286ddb94018eb5f1.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\_version.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111755 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'gdal-7f64690bf4c72c16286ddb94018eb5f1.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\_env.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111755 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'gdal-7f64690bf4c72c16286ddb94018eb5f1.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\_features.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111756 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'gdal-7f64690bf4c72c16286ddb94018eb5f1.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\_base.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111756 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'gdal-7f64690bf4c72c16286ddb94018eb5f1.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\_err.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111756 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'gdal-7f64690bf4c72c16286ddb94018eb5f1.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\_filepath.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111756 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'gdal-7f64690bf4c72c16286ddb94018eb5f1.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\_io.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111757 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'gdal-7f64690bf4c72c16286ddb94018eb5f1.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\crs.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111757 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'libopenblas64__v0.3.23-293-gc2f4bdbb-gcc_10_3_0-2bde3a66a51006b2b53eb373ff767a3f.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\_multiarray_umath.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111757 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'libopenblas64__v0.3.23-293-gc2f4bdbb-gcc_10_3_0-2bde3a66a51006b2b53eb373ff767a3f.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\linalg\\_umath_linalg.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111758 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'gdal-7f64690bf4c72c16286ddb94018eb5f1.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\_warp.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111761 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'msvcp140-fa0758dedafbbe194d3ee96e3dc2b9a3.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\_libs\\window\\aggregations.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111762 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'gdal-fd9ba3209f601e85fe39e4d1757194df.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\fiona\\schema.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111762 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'gdal-fd9ba3209f601e85fe39e4d1757194df.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\fiona\\_err.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111762 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'gdal-fd9ba3209f601e85fe39e4d1757194df.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\fiona\\_geometry.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111762 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'gdal-fd9ba3209f601e85fe39e4d1757194df.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\fiona\\ogrext.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111763 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'gdal-fd9ba3209f601e85fe39e4d1757194df.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\fiona\\crs.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111763 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'gdal-fd9ba3209f601e85fe39e4d1757194df.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\fiona\\_env.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111763 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'proj-6a9d00a0da816213800e2fe688403951.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\pyproj\\_sync.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111764 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'proj-6a9d00a0da816213800e2fe688403951.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\pyproj\\_transformer.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111764 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'proj-6a9d00a0da816213800e2fe688403951.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\pyproj\\_crs.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111764 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'proj-6a9d00a0da816213800e2fe688403951.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\pyproj\\list.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111765 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'proj-6a9d00a0da816213800e2fe688403951.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\pyproj\\_geod.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111765 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'proj-6a9d00a0da816213800e2fe688403951.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\pyproj\\database.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111765 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'proj-6a9d00a0da816213800e2fe688403951.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\pyproj\\_datadir.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111765 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'proj-6a9d00a0da816213800e2fe688403951.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\lib\\site-packages\\pyproj\\_network.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'.
111766 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'cares.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\JacobNordberg\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcpro_testing\\Library\\bin\\arrow_flight.dll'.
112064 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\JacobNordberg\Documents\GitHub\Point-to-Line2\build\ptlgui\warn-ptlgui.txt
112821 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\JacobNordberg\Documents\GitHub\Point-to-Line2\build\ptlgui\xref-ptlgui.html
113152 INFO: checking PYZ
113153 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
113154 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\JacobNordberg\Documents\GitHub\Point-to-Line2\build\ptlgui\PYZ-00.pyz
121224 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\JacobNordberg\Documents\GitHub\Point-to-Line2\build\ptlgui\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
121758 INFO: checking PKG
121758 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
121759 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) ptlgui.pkg
229467 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) ptlgui.pkg completed successfully.
229647 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\JacobNordberg\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcpro_testing\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit-intel\run.exe
229647 INFO: checking EXE
229649 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
229649 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
229649 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\Users\JacobNordberg\Documents\GitHub\Point-to-Line2\dist\ptlgui.exe
229735 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
229804 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
229804 INFO: Embedding manifest in EXE
229887 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
230165 INFO: Fixing EXE headers
247076 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Please let me know if any other information would be helpful in solving this. Any help is greatly appreciated!